# addIfEmpty - does this exist?

Tags: jquery, addition

In many places would like to have a function that adds to the set of currently matched elements (like `.add()`) but *only* if the current set is actually *empty*.

An example:

`$obj.closest(".myItem").addIfEmpty("body")` 
 --> only `add` "body" if there is no `.myItem` around

Is there such a function in jquery  ?   Or what is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't exist, but you can make it

```
$.fn.addIfEmpty = function(arg) {
    return this.length > 0 ? this : $(arg);
}
```

Comment: really -  It's that simple ;-) ?  BTW, would you say this is a generally useful addition to jQuery ?

Comment: That depends on you. If you need something like this, it's useful